# how to create a for loop to put a series of pics in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have 20 pics in one folder. I want to create one table with 20 cells. First I want to put all images in one array and then give the source to every cell. I mean `[0].src` is the picture cell one shows. The problem is I don't want to repeat my code 20 times for every index.

```
 <table id="game" align="left" width="100" height="100" border="2">

<tr>

<td class="fruitCells" id="cel1"><img id="img1" /></td>

<td class="fruitCells" id="cel2"><img src=images/image_apples.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel3"><img src=images/oranges.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel4"><img src=images/oranges.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel5"><img src=images/mangos.jpg /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel6"><img src=images/mangos.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel7"><img src=images/grapes.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel8"><img src=images/grapes.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel9"><img src=images/cherrys.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel10"><img src=images/cherrys.jpg /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel11"><img src=images/apricots.jpg  /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel12"><img src=images/apricots.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel13"><img src=images/plums.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel14"><img src=images/plums.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel15"><img src=images/pears.jpg /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel16"><img src=images/pears.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel17"><img src=images/peaches.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel18"><img src=images/peaches.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel19"><img src=images/kiwi.jpg /></td>
<td class="fruitCells" id="cel20"><img src=images/kiwi.jpg /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>

</table>
<script>
// it doesn't work
var fruitArray = new Array(19);

for (var i= 0;i <20;i++) {
   fruitArray[i] = new Image();
   fruitArray[i].src = "images/image_" + i + ".jpg";
}

//this one works

fruitArray[0] = new Image();
fruitArray[0].src = "images/apples.jpg"

fruitArray[1] = new Image();
fruitArray[1].src = "images/oranges.jpg"

fruitArray[2] = new Image();
fruitArray[2].src = "images/mangos.jpg"

fruitArray[3] = new Image();
fruitArray[3].src = "images/grapes.jpg"

fruitArray[4] = new Image();
fruitArray[4].src = "images/cherrys.jpg"

fruitArray[5] = new Image();
fruitArray[5].src = "images/apricots.jpg"

fruitArray[6] = new Image();
fruitArray[6].src = "images/plums.jpg"

fruitArray[7] = new Image();
fruitArray[7].src = "images/pears.jpg"

fruitArray[8] = new Image();
fruitArray[8].src = "images/peaches.jpg"

fruitArray[9] = new Image();
fruitArray[9].src = "images/kiwi.jpg"

fruitArray[10] = new Image();
fruitArray[10].src = "images/apples.jpg"

fruitArray[11] = new Image();
fruitArray[11].src = "images/oranges.jpg"

fruitArray[12] = new Image();
fruitArray[12].src = "images/mangos.jpg"

fruitArray[13] = new Image();
fruitArray[13].src = "images/grapes.jpg"

fruitArray[14] = new Image();
fruitArray[14].src = "images/cherrys.jpg"

fruitArray[15] = new Image();
fruitArray[15].src = "images/apricots.jpg"

fruitArray[16] = new Image();
fruitArray[16].src = "images/plums.jpg"

fruitArray[17] = new Image();
fruitArray[17].src = "images/pears.jpg"

fruitArray[18] = new Image();
fruitArray[18].src = "images/peaches.jpg"

fruitArray[19] = new Image();
fruitArray[19].src = "images/kiwi.jpg"


document.getElementById("img1").src = fruitArray[0].src;
</script>`
```

How can I loop?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything, or are you just asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I didn't try the for loop.I am a beginner.I repeated the code 20 times.it was frustrating.so i asked.by the way i read some pages like [link](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/image-array-using-javascript/).

Comment: You should study the basics of the language you are using. Then when you run into a problem, come here. Do research first. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: @Ajk_P thanks for great help but how,what's the condition?the code inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the loop:

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 0;i < 20) {
    a[i] = new Image();
    a[i].src = "images/image_" + i + ".jpg";
}
```

You will need to rename your images so they have an index.

Comment: thanks for the answer,but in the second line we need a counter,and it doesn't work.`document.getElementById("img1").src = a[0].src` it doesn't show the pic.

Comment: If you were able to give me a snippet of the exact code that would be great. It's hard for me to blindly help you not knowing all the specifics. I just gave you an example that you could modify.

Comment: The problem is that you need to have your images indexed numerically so a loop can be created to access them. Not only that, but you're not telling us if the table is created dynamically or not. Is the html already all there for the table?

Comment: i have the table in an html page.but when i run the loop code there are no pics in the cells,but line by line it works.